# Undefined symbols for architecture i386/armv7 [cocoapods]

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, armv7, i386

After installing a custom pod with `$ pod install` command, I can't build the project because there are some errors like below (on my Xcode the error is about **armv7**, on an another Xcode, the error is about **i386 architecture**):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_generateCombMatrix", referenced from:
      -[className method:] in libPods-Bot-betting-core.a(ClassName)
  "_debugLog", referenced from:
  -[ClassName Method:] in libPods-Bot-betting-core.a(className.o)
  -[ClassName method] in libPods-Bot-betting-core.a(className.o)
  -[className method] in libPods-Bot-betting-core.a(className.o)
  -[className method:] in libPods-Bot-betting-core.a(className.o)
  -[className method:] in libPods-Bot-betting-core.a(className.o)
  -[className method] in libPods-Bot-betting-core.a(className.o)
  -[className method] in libPods-Bot-betting-core.a(className.o)
  -[className method] in libPods-Bot-betting-core.a(className.o)
  ...
  "_SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO", referenced from:
  -[className init] in libPods-Bot-betting-core.a(className.o)
```

Files mentioned in the error are in the project **Pods** and the libPods.a library is correctly linked to the project.
This is the .xconfig file on debug (on release is the same):

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/betting-core"
OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/betting-core"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC -l"Pods-Bot-betting-core"
OTHER_LIBTOOLFLAGS = $(OTHER_LDFLAGS)
PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
```

The library support the architecture as you can see in the screen below:
[image: supported architecture]

Comment: And does the library support the `armv7` CPU architecture?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes, I edited the first post with a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar problem today. I was able to resolve the issue by deleting all derived data: Windows -> Projects -> Select your workspace -> click "Delete..." next to "Derived Data" on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me

**Make sure your Project targets have  $(inherited) present in the Other Linker Flags in Build Settings.**